# Allow random order of elements some with repeating and some without repeating in a XSD schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to create an XSD, and trying to write the definition with the following requirement:

```
Allow child elements specified to appear only once, but one elements to appear multiple times
Allow child elements to be in any order
```

Example:

```
<parent>
<child1/>
<child2/>
<child3/>
<child3/>
</parent>
```

The child1 and child2 elements must be able to exchange the order but should not be repeated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible in general in XSD 1.0, except by listing all the possible permutations as @kjhughes has done, which becomes unmanageable if you have more than say 4 permitted element children.

In XSD 1.1 you can write

```
<xs:all>
  <xs:element name="child1"/>
  <xs:element name="child2"/>
  <xs:element name="child3" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:all>
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple, v1.0, XSD will require a `parent` with exactly one `child1` and one `child2`, in any order, among any number of `child3`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="parent">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="child3" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:choice>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="child1"/>
            <xs:element name="child3" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="child2"/>
            <xs:element name="child3" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="child2"/>
            <xs:element name="child3" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="child1"/>
            <xs:element name="child3" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```